# Difference between two stack size (using size()) in std::cout

Tags: c++, stl, size

I am confused why the two print statements give different output. Attaching the code snippet below. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

```
    stack<int>st1;
    stack<int>st2;
    
    st2.push(222);
    
    cout<<"st1 size:"<<st1.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"st2 size:"<<st2.size()<<endl;
    
    int a=st1.size();
    int b=st2.size();
    cout<<"difference:"<<a-b<<endl;
    cout<<"difference:"<<(st1.size()-st2.size())<<endl; //why this is giving different ans
    /* output:
        st1 size:0
        st2 size:1
        difference:-1
        difference:4294967295
     */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the return type of the member function `size`. I bet that you'll find it is an unsigned type.

What happens when you calculate 0u - 1 with unsigned integers? The result cannot be -1 because that number isn't representable by an unsigned type. The result will be a positive number that is congruent with -1 modulo the number of representable values. Which is also the largest value representable by that unsigned type.

Comment: You already answered this question in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh cool. That's 4 years ago :)

Comment: Got it, thankyou  so much..!!!

Comment: `int difference = st1.size() - st2.size()` What would be the value of `difference` (assuming st2 is larger than st1)?

Comment: @skpro19 First the subtraction result would be some large positive value congruent with the negative result modulo the representable values of the unsigned type, then if that value isn't representable as `int`, then the converted value will be a representable value that is congruent with the afore mentioned positive value modulo the number of representable values of `int`. That's since C++20. Prior to that the conversion of unrepresentable value to a signed integer would be implementation defined (but in practice same as C++20 guaranteed result on 2's complement systems). TL;DR some value :)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is because `int` is a signed type while [`std::stack::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/size) returns an unsigned value.

Calculation of unsigned integer wraps around when the result is going to out of the range of value that can be represented by the type.